# Decode and Decrypt Azure B2C OpenID Authorization Token, Use Response in API Call (Example Token Within)

Tags: php, javascript, authentication, encryption

I have been provided with a working Azure AD B2C application, and my goal is to use it to facilitate a means of access control to particular content.

Using that application URL, a successful login/authentication results in a redirect (in accordance with the redirect-URI) with an id_token appended. Here's an example:

```
https://dev.domain.org/#id_token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IkxKTnZUd1g3Wm9qZnRHUWhXUEdid0hpZExzU3VSVEYyRDh2WjA4d3lpbjgifQ.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.Nwx_uH9hbo0OHoeOlq0YYgS5rLqJK_PV5WulIlfnl4z-tY6jGF_jjEZ7VLpNGD9qivy70E1mfoxOuVkFPTIidScmMJSu_Ps5sNgvxLHNPPI_n5ufDcVo2zztAfS-SCLHXlLGsMXnfjDwDzEO2GQaCM3U66VaVzVXeeMVPSW0VBbyt3TM3jhnPE8BML5YqTWg0OMYFMUivRth1Ydf6sjbSvJzWsRNOv2I6NC2iAicVZ-mQAiBF2QJJPxPMHdwmwxt-qiA81q69BiylGlUFQQ3MthiJ1BztjtIGUYLgs6kI09-YPt881UjsFbVpS0D1CAs3PiqtQ1dgp0DHLmSz7c4oA
```

The value of the id_token is encoded and encrypted, so it will need to be decoded and then decrypted. The encoding is Base 64 and the encryption is specified after decoding, which I believe should be easily handled by open source libraries (but I've failed to figure out how). Using jwt.io, I can tell you that the decoded and decrypted data contains first name, last name, email address and the member’s ID in this format:

```
"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/vendorid":"811428101",
"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress":"autosiicpzr.qatesting@cfaqa.testinator.com",
"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name":"autosiicpzr.qatesting@cfaqa.testinator.com",
"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/givenname":"mAFdC",
"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/surname":"pZnKq",
"http://schemas.microsoft.com/accesscontrolservice/2010/07/claims/identityprovider":"AzureB2C"
```

The member ID is returned as ‘vendorId’. So in the above example, the member/vendor ID (811428101) would then be used to look up the user’s membership status via an API I have access to.

Using vanilla Javascript or PHP, how do I decode and decrypt the response and store it for use (the vendorId parameter, most crucially) in the subsequent API query?

If helpful, the API request URL would look something like this:

```
https://apigateway.test.domain.org/TestPublic/users/{vendorId}
```

Comment: Is this a WordPress question? Generic PHP/JS questions should be asked on stackoverflow

Comment: Sorry. I guess it could potentially be considered a generic PHP/JS question, but implementation is in fact going to occur on a WordPress site. I had initially considered posing a question revolving around a deeper SSO integration, whereby WP users would automatically be provisioned upon the user's initial successful authentication, but I thought that might be a bridge too far in terms of the request for help. If I add that piece, is it then (and only then) appropriate for wordpress.stackexchange?

Comment: honestly that part sounds like it might be a follow up question, but unless you need WordPress expertise to answer this question it's best it goes on stackoverflow instead. Anybody with PHP knowledge even if they don't know WP can answer it, the expertise you need is OpenID, you shouldn't limit yourself to WP developers unnecessarily. You want a specific question that's clear and unambiguous, you can create new questions for other things, just be clear on the context and avoid the X Y problem trap

Comment: I very sincerely appreciate that, Tom. Thank you for the guidance.